# Changing target of pointer in function (to a dynamically created object)

Tags: c++, function, pointers

That may well be silly, but I'm going crazy here ..

Why does pTest doesnt point on the new int after test function in main ? It causes seg fault. And how can I do it.

In my real code I need to pass a pointer and dynamically create the object because pTest is a subclass of a virtual class (reading from file so I don't know in advance)

```
void test(int* pTest)
{
    int *p = new int(2);
    pTest = p;
    std::cout << "pTest : " << *pTest << std::endl;
    return;
}

int main()
{
  int *pTest = NULL;
  test(pTest);
  std::cout << "pTest : " << *pTest << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I swear there's *at least* one question precisely like this every day...

Comment: Please search SO. There are a lot of duplicates.

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't think of searching. I bet the ones asking for it everyday also had a hard time coming with a title for their question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between value parameter and reference parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207179/difference-between-value-parameter-and-reference-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass pTest by reference: `void test(int*& pTest)` if you want the `pTest` value to be altered outside the scope of this function.

```
void test(int*& pTest)
{
    int *p = new int(2);
    pTest = p;
    std::cout << "pTest : " << *pTest << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

Comment: And instead of providing one of the million dubplicates, that I can't find because I don't know what to search for you make a comment about him not doing so..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mutate value passed as a parameter you have to provide pointer to it. That means if you want to change value of a given int you are passing int* . In your case you want to mutate int* so that you need to pass it as int** instead.