# No suitable constructor to convert from int to emp

Tags: c++

My program simply is to increase the salary int the emp class throw the the function increase 
but I'm having this error int the call function line from the line : 
No suitable constructor to convert from int to emp

here 's my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class emp
{
public:
int salary;
};

void increase(emp x,emp y)
{
    x.salary+=100;
y.salary+=250;

}

int main()
{
int value=0;
emp fst, scnd;
cin >> fst.salary >> scnd.salary;
increase(fst.salary,scnd.salary);
cout << fst.salary << endl << scnd.salary << endl; 

cin >> value;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`increase` expects two `emp`s as parameters, yet you pass in two `int`s.

Change

```
increase(fst.salary,scnd.salary);
```

to

```
increase(fst,scnd);
```

Your next question is going to be why the values don't change, so to save you the trouble - it's because you're passing by value, effectively changing copies of your original objects. You'll need to pass by reference:

```
void increase(emp& x,emp& y)
```

Comment: yet sir there's no increasing happened ?!

Answer (score 0):

`increase(fst.salary,scnd.salary);` should be `increase(fst,scnd);`, `void increase(emp x,emp y) ...` should be `void increase(emp& x,emp& y) ...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `emp` not `int`. Further, you are passing parameters by value. Use this instead:

```
void increase(emp &x,emp &y)
```

And pass the struct variables; i.e. fst and scnd instead of fst.salary and scnd.salary. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207179/difference-between-value-parameter-and-reference-parameter) question for better understanding.